# Ticket booking query in mysql, based on date, destination and return date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing ticket booking system

Let me try to explain what i need. I have table that contains date of trip, amount of persons, start point, end point, type of ticket, and return date. Ticket can be one-way, daily, or return ticket (where buyer can select day of return).

Here is the problem, if 5 persons buy ticket for lets say 21.12.2013, for destination A to B, but they all buy daily ticket which means they will all return same day and their destination will be B to A at the time of return.

And one more person buys ticket for 21.12.2013 but from destination B to A, i need sum of persons to be 6.

I'm also generating some barcodes on my ticket so if buyer selects daily or return ticket, i need two query's, one to calculate sum of persons (bookings) on starting date, and second for return date.

So basically table looks like this

> ```
> id |   date   | persons  | paid | destinationA | destinationB | typeofticket |return_date
>  --+----------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------
>  1 |21.12.2013|   5      |  yes |      1       |      2       |   daily      |21.12.2013
>  2 |21.12.2013|   1      |  yes |      2       |      1       |   one-way    |21.12.2013
>  2 |21.12.2013|   2      |  no  |      2       |      1       |   one-way    |21.12.2013
> ```

So any suggestions what should my query look a like ? i have something like this (which is obviously wrong):

```
$query1 = "
SELECT date, SUM(persons) totalpersons FROM table_name
WHERE date='$date' AND (destinationA ='$destinationA') OR
(destinationA ='$destinationB' AND typeofticket = 'Daily')
";


$query2 = "
SELECT date, SUM(persons) totalpersons FROM table_name
WHERE date='$return_date' AND (destinationA ='$destinationA') OR
(destinationB ='$destinationA' AND typeofticket = 'Daily')
";
```

If some of strings on names are not correct, it's because i was translating field names frommy language to english for this post :(

I'm just looking for some tips on how to approach to this query's ... thanks in advance.

Here is what's working atm, but i'm 100% sure im still missing something : ) and yes i need query to look only paid tickets:

```
$query_b1 = "
SELECT date, SUM(persons) totalpersons FROM table_name
WHERE date='$date' AND  paid='yes' AND (destA='$destA' AND destB='$destB' OR
(destB='$destA' AND typeofticket ='Daily')
)";
```

Comment: You could consider modelling a journey separately to a ticket. i.e. each ticket can have 1 or more associated journeys. A simple group by query can then be used to get to the count that you require.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about that too, but there has to be some query that will work this way, so i do not have to rewrite code.

Comment: can you post some more sample data and your expected results? from your sample data I see 8 people going from 2 to 1 for that date

Comment: maybe you're only looking at people who have `paid` not sure what you're expecting

Comment: Ok, here is the deal, the above edited query will give correct results but it will ignore all tickets that have different start date, but same return date, so should i use UNION and have multiple WHERE: Where date='$date' (query) UNION dateofreturn='$dateofreturn' (query) . I think that is correct logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have is actually correct, minus a typo (you have "='Daily'" instead of "='daily'"). Here's my version:

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(persons) as totalpersons
FROM table_name
WHERE `date`='$date'
    AND (
        (destinationB > destinationA)
        OR (destinationA > destinationB AND typeofticket='daily')
    )
```

It might also be a good idea to rename your destination columns to `origin` and `destination` for clarity, and put the place names in the fields. So your query would then look like this:

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(persons) as totalpersons
FROM table_name
WHERE `date`='$date'
    AND (
        (
            origin = '$origin' 
            AND destination = '$destination'
        )
        OR (
            origin = '$destination' 
            AND destination = '$origin' 
            AND typeofticket='daily'
        )
    )
```

You could just use this query twice, but switch the origin and destination for the return trip.

Comment: Ok i'm close to final solution. this is working, but it still has some errors.